# How to cast a string to Enum case in swift?

Tags: swift, enums

```
enum Numbers{
    case One
    case Two
    case Three
}

func(name: String) {
    // I have to convert name to Numbers 
    // or I have to search name is existed as an enum case
}
```

I get name string dynamically. So I want to convert the above **'str'** to **enum Numbers**. Please anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You should simply declare your `enum` to have a `String` `rawValue`, then you can initialise the `enum` from a `String` for free.

```
enum Number: String {
    case one = "One"
    case two = "Two"
    case three = "Three"
}

let str = "One"
let number = Number(rawValue: str)
```

Bear in mind that enum names should be singular and enum cases should be lowerCamelCase in Swift.